# How to convert API stock data to table using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

my API response is like this

```
{
'1644205500': {'date': '06-02-2022', 'open': 501.85, 'high': 504.2, 'low': 500.75, 'close': 503.05}, 
'1644205800': {'date': '06-02-2022', 'open': 502.85, 'high': 503.05, 'low': 497.45, 'close': 498.55},
'1644206100': {'date': '06-02-2022', 'open': 498.85, 'high': 498.85, 'low': 495.3, 'close': 498.75}, 
'1644206400': {'date': '06-02-2022', 'open': 498.7, 'high': 498.75, 'low': 497.2, 'close': 498.05}, 
'1644206700': {'date': '06-02-2022', 'open': 497.95, 'high': 498.85, 'low': 496.45, 'close': 496.45}, 
'1644207000': {'date': '06-02-2022', 'open': 496.45, 'high': 498, 'low': 496.45, 'close': 497.5}
}
```

When I use `pd.json_normalize(data)` there is only one row and so many columns. Like this:

```
1644205500.date 1644205500.open 1644205500.high 1644205500.low  1644205500.close 1644205800.date    1644205800.open 1644205800.high 1644205800.low  1644205800.close 1644206100.date    1644206100.open 1644206100.high 1644206100.low  1644206100.close
```

How can I make it like a table like this?

```
date            open   high   low   close
06-02-2022       500    501    490    501
06-02-2022       501    502    480    470
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.values())
```

**EDIT (see comments)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.values()).assign(timestamp=data.keys())
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the '1644205500' inside a column called timestamp?  So that columns will be 'timestamp', 'date', 'open', 'high', 'low' and 'close'